# Why does .match() stop my code from executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

I'm having trouble with a form I'm trying to validate. I'm trying to make sure for the email input that the email is the correct format, and if it is not I'll be able to send an error message to the user. Unfortunately, I can't get the return false; to execute.

Here is my current code:

```
function validate(){
    var email = $('input.email').value;
    var emailRE = /^.*@.+\..{2,5}$/;
    if (email.match(emailRE)){
        alert("This is true");
    } else {
        alert("This isn't true.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I execute this, the page reloads and the form submits, and neither alert goes off. However, when I take out the whole if, else section, the return false; executes, and the page doesn't reload. I also tried taking out just the '.match()', and the code executed fine. So what is wrong with the .match() part that's causing it to fail?

Any help is extremely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What browser are you testing this with btw?  The regex you have posted, while likely not what you want for a number of reasons, is well-formed and should not cause `match` to throw an exception.  Are you certain that `email` is getting the value you expect?  It is likely that `email` is not actually a string and whatever it is (possibly `undefined`) has no `match` method.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `$('input.email').val()` instead of `$('input.email').value`

http://jsfiddle.net/bMJH2/6/

`value` is for the DOM object.  But the object you are dealing with is a jQuery object, so the proper way is to use `val()`.  If you run it in Firefox/Firebug using `value`, it will show the error:

```
email is undefined
[Break On This Error] if (email.match(emailRE)){
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! However, the page still does not execute the return false or the alerts. It reloads the page with the same "symptoms." Any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: I take that back! You are most definitely correct! It turns out I was loading the class, but I gave the element an ID attribute. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated. ;)